# Get the whole file path or upload file use bash shell cgi

Tags: bash, shell, file-upload

I want to get the file path of select file, but the file path can not be read according to the security of browser itself .
For example, firefox just read filename(ex test.txt).
Concerned about it, what can I do to read the file path of file button selected in bash shell scripting?
The reason I need the file path is that I want to upload the file to the server, so I want to use command cp to do it, like:

`cp filepath(and filename) serverpath`

Can I use simple button(type=button instead type=file) to do it with special method(with a type=text to do the trick)?
The original code I tried is:

```
#!/bin/sh

#=================================================
#   PATH defination
# ================================================



#=================================================
#   Main
# ================================================
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo "Pragma: no-cache"
echo ""
echo "<HTML><HEAD>"
echo "<meta http-equiv=content-type content=text/html; charset=UTF-8>"
echo "<TITLE>$msg010</TITLE>"
. ${WWW_SCRIPTS_LIB_PATH}/style-init.sh
echo "</HEAD>"
echo "<BODY>"
ShowSubLogo "$msg010"

if [ "$CONTENT_LENGTH" != "" ]; then
    read data
    filesplit1=`echo $data | awk -F'&' '{print $1}'`

if [ "$filesplit1" != "fileis=" ]; then
    filename=`echo $filesplit1 | sed "s/%20/ /g" | cut -f 2 -d "="`
fi

fi

echo "<br> </br>"
echo "<br> </br>"
echo "$msg050"
echo "<br> </br>"
echo "<form name=Updfw_form method=post action=EippsUpdate.cgi>"
echo "$msg020"
echo "<input name='fileis' id='UpLoad' type='file'>"
echo "<br> </br>"
echo "<input name='update' value='$msg030' class=bton_over value=\"$com010\" type='submit' onmouseover=\"this.className='bton_out'\" onmouseout=\"this.className='bton_over'\">"
echo "<input name='cancel' value='$msg040' class=bton_over value=\"$com010\" type='reset' onmouseover=\"this.className='bton_out'\" onmouseout=\"this.className='bton_over'\">"
echo "</form>"
echo "</BODY></HTML>"
```

It just read the filename, and in crome browser, it can not work.

Or is there another way to upload a file to server that user can select?
I searched and seldom look the example of bash shell version.

Just the whole filepath! Or upload file to browser!

Any answer appreciate.

Comment: I'm not sure to right understand: Is that a `client` or `server` script?  Are you writting CGI (server side) in shell?

Comment: I'm not sure what .cgi file is too... But it can handle both  client side and  server side. And I think it is server side.

The code I post can "echo $filename" to show the filename in firefox and IE, but crome browser can not...
(The code is not fully, just partial)
So I want another method to get the filename( and whole path). Or another way to upload file to server( and the file can be selected by user)

Comment: The code sample is indeed CGI script in POSIX shell. CGI script runs on the server side.

Comment: What are you trying to do that the file path on client is relevant to the server? In any case I can imagine the paths actually match there is probably a better solution using some other protocol like SSH or SFTP or FTP or somesuch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. IE is buggy in telling you. While I am not really sure how to abuse it, I am rather confident it's a security problem that it does.

You have to add another input field where the user will fill in the path where the file should be stored on the server.

To be honest for web application, manipulated by human (rather than web service called by specific client program), I don't see a reason why the path on the client and path on the server would have anything in common. By providing separate input field you are giving the user freedom to place the file wherever they want on the local machine.

If they actually have to be the same, than there probably is some common application and you can bundle script that will do the upload (possibly over some more suitable protocol like ssh, either calling receiving script or with scp or sftp) with appropriate path.

On a side-note, shell is not well suited to CGI programming, because it's use of special characters makes it rather difficult to secure properly.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use input field!